# Filter array of objects by name and multiple substrings

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have an array of objects which I want to filter by the key `name`.

Furthermore, I want to check, if this `name` contains any of given substrings.

Example:

```json
{
 "name": "this is the name"
}
```

When searching for `this name`, it should be contained in the result list.
How can I achieve this?

What I currently have:

```java
const filteredData = query
    ? totalItems
        ?.filter((x: DBItemResponse) =>
          x?.name.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase()))
    : totalItems
```

Which returns me a sublist of all objects which contain **one** substring.

For example, if `query` is `this is the`, i would get the object as a result. If `query` was `this name`, the object would not be contained in the result array.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So all the words in the query should be present in the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's get the "words" by splitting the query with spaces. But then if there are multiple spaces (or other whitespace) between words, you'll get empty strings and words with whitespace at the ends. So let's use regex instead.

```
query.split(/\s+/)
```

Here we are splitting by any continuous whitespace with `\s+`.

After we get the words, we want *every* word to be present in the results.

Do that with the aptly named `every` method:

```
query.split(/\s+/).every((word) => ...)
```

And now it's like your original code:

```
query.toLowerCase().split(/\s+/).every((word) => x?.name.toLowerCase().includes(word))
```

You should also make the `query` lowercase before using it, so you don't have to call `.toLowerCase()` on every word for every `x` to test.

This should replace your existing filter.